# Can I empty my connected account to end a contract?

Tags: united-states

I have a situation similar to [Insurance - Forced to call for cancellation](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59783/insurance-forced-to-call-for-cancellation)

I currently have an insurance policy that I do not need anymore.

I have tried to cancel my policy but I cannot do it on my own. The website only enables me to contact the company via phone or email. I have tried contacting the company but they have not responded, while having me charged once more for a monthly auto renewal.

I am led to wonder what would happen if I simply move all the deposits in the account subject to auto renewal

jurisdiction: US(Pennsylvania)

Comment: Or ask your bank to not transfer any money to that company.

Comment: This is why it's always best to "push" automatic payments through your bank rather than give them permission to "pull" it from you.  Then you control the spigot.

Comment: The Consumer Financial Protection Bureau is swiftly losing patience with services that make it prohibitively difficult to cancel. You may have some success by filing a report through their web site.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contract/policy wording. Basically, there could be 2 approaches typed in the fine print:

1. Contract automatically ends after a certain period since a continuing payment failure starts. Say 2 consecutive payments fail, that's it.
2. Contract endures any payment failures until explicitly ended. Failed payments accrue debt which will need to be paid up in any event.

I've never heard of any insurance company entertaining option #2. But it is possible, so check the wording.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you'll be able to end a contract by simply not paying - by moving funds, closing the linked account, or instructing your bank to refuse any requests for payment - unless you have something that says otherwise. I've said "unlikely" as it's possible that a contract could contain terms that terminate the contract for a missed payment, but unless you can see words that specifically state that, it's best to assume that charges will continue to accumulate.

Another approach would be to send [registered mail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_mail) to the insurance company's registered address stating your intention to end the agreement, ideally on a specified date. The record of receipt - or of a failed delivery attempt - will be useful if the company should try to take legal action against you for accumulated charges. Keep copies of all e-mails and post, and records of any phone calls - including unanswered attempts. That would then be the time to consider blocking payment, though if you wanted to be sure it would be wise to do this on the suggestion of a legal professional.

It's worth mentioning here that you now have much better grounds to terminate the contract. A customer being unable to reach the company - possibly in the event of a claim - would be a failure to meet the fundamental expectations a customer would have of an insurance company.

Comment: I had one insurance that explicitly said: To cancel the insurance, just cancel your Direct Debit.

Comment: @gnasher729 - I'd not seen one myself, but it made sense it could be done. I'll rearrange the first two paragraphs.

Comment: @MichaelHall - I agree they'd play it that way if it suited them. What I'm not able to rule out is that they might regard missed payments as a debt when that suits them better. It sounds like your insurer tried that approach at first, but you weren't having it. Kudos to you, but the OP might not be so fortunate (or persuasive).

Answer (score 0):

Your contractual requirement to make payments, and the ability of the company to collect the payments, are completely different things. If the contract allows auto-renewal, then the company can renew, and the contract is not necessarily voided by your lack of payment (although it depends on the wording). It likely is void*able*, however, which is a dangerous thing in the case of an insurance policy.

With something like, say, Netflix, they have to choose between allowing you to continue having the service, in which case at least you're still getting something out of it, you shutting off your service, in which case you can probably argue that they have voided the contract and you don't owe further payments. With an insurance company, however, they can wait to see if you make a claim, and if you don't they say that the policy was still in effect, and you owe the premiums, and if you do, they say that the policy wasn't in effect because you hadn't paid.

While stopping payment doesn't necessarily end the contract, the contract arguably is already stopped. The contract may have said they can auto-renew, but it probably doesn't say they can auto-renew regardless of your attempts to cancel, and even if it did, you have the arguments of that being unconscionable, and that you didn't understand that when you agreed to it and there therefore wasn't meeting of the minds.

If you have decided that you don't want the policy anymore, and you have made reasonable attempts to communicate that to them, and their lack of awareness of this can be attributed to their refusal to allow communication, then you have a strong case that the contract has already ended. I recommend contacting the company in a way that's leaves a record (e.g. recording yourself calling them up, saying "This phone call is being recorded", then saying "I am hereby cancelling my policy", and if they don't pick up, that's on them), then if they continue to charge you, report the transaction to your bank as fraudulent.